# How to script a batch that automatically creates a tag increment?

Tags: python, windows, git, batch-file

I'd like to automate a git Windows-based python-scaffold setup and to that end I'd like to create a batch that does something along the following lines (I will highlight what I am missing):

```
 @ clean untracked files, I know may be dangerous ...
 git clean -fd 
 git checkout master
 @ check whether the last commit is tagged i.e. nothing to do:
 git log -1 > % ??? get the last commit, load the tag name into a variable 
 @ and check whether it's tagged e.g. commit 2acaa06fb1b5aa8e804dc37ca2fc53d6c4369b6a (HEAD -> master, tag: v1.2.9, origin/master)
 @ we see that this one is tagged so we skip the next step
 @ at this point %LAST_TAG% should equal 1.2.9 
 if empty %LAST_TAG%:
    @ find the last tag from git log
    git log > % ??? get the last tag into %LAST_TAG%
    @ increment it, e.g. should be v1.2.10 how to do this in batch?
    NEXT_TAG = increment(%LAST_TAG%)
    git tag -a %NEXT_TAG% -m "Maintenance release, automated increment"
    @ push the next tag to origin
    git push origin --tags
    
    @create the released binary artifact
    git checkout -b %NEXT_TAG% %NEXT_TAG%
    python setup.py bdist_wheel
    @ find the lastest file in folder
    FOR /f %f IN ('dir /b /od dist\*.whl') DO @SET NEWEST_WHL=%f
    pip install dist\%NEWEST_WHL%
```

Comment: It looks to me as if you're trying to determine how to populate a variable named `LAST_TAG` with the returned value from a command. To do that, you use exactly the same method as you're already using to populate `NEWEST_WHL`. Open a Command Prompt window, type `for /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read the usage information. Pay particular attention to the use of `Delims`, `EOF`, `Skip`, `Tokens`, and `UseBackQ` you may need one or more of those to isolate thae particular string you require from the returned data.

Comment: Is your strategy that all merges into master should increment the 2nd number and set the 3rd number to 0? If yes, what is the process that increments the 3rd number?

Comment: @TTT Yes these are minor release increments so will suffice incrementing only the third number indefinitely i.e. 1-until whatever 11, 12, .., +inf

Comment: Since you have python, do your scripting in python (or sh which comes with git). Save yourself and followers some nerve cells.

Comment: @ddbug Hahaha :-D you're right ... I wish but this is a Win env and at the point where this is executed i cant assume anything i.e. python installation or version etc .. my hands are tied.